# Mule flowvars getting affected which preserves payload when the payload is changed

Tags: foreach, mule

I am storing the output from DB in a flowvar **#[flowvars.test]** after which I am **iterating the payload to remove few key, value pair**. when the payload is modified inside the for loop the value which is stored in flowvars also getting modified.I am using mule 3.9 runtime.

```
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select MachineName,TransactionId,SourceAPIName,Source,Target,ErrorCode,Severity,MailContent,ExceptionType,ExceptionMessage from Notification
     where Notify='Y' and IsNotify='N']]>
                 </db:select>
             </poll>
             <expression-filter expression="#[payload.size()&gt;0]" doc:name="Stop If No Records"/>
             <set-variable variableName="test" value="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
<set-variable variableName="validatedEntries" value="#[[]]"
            doc:name="ValidatedEntries" />
                     <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                     <foreach collection="#[flowVars.test]" doc:name="For Each">
                 <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                 <set-variable variableName="tempNotificationTable" value="#[payload.remove('TransactionID')]" doc:name="Temp NotificationTable"/>
                 <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[#[flowVars.validatedEntries.add(payload)]]]></expression-component>
             </foreach>
```

Comment: Wherever any flowvars has reference of #[payload] is getting modified. I am using Mule 3.9 runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For-Each will not create a deep copy of the object. Because of this, your original payload is getting changed.